# I have this error org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json, parsing

This is my code and I am using json and volley I want to show response in next activity please tell me your answer in detail because I am new in android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn_logn;
EditText et_1, et_2;
String url;


String username, password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_one);
    et_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass_two);


    btn_logn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btn_logn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            login();
        }
    });
}

public void login() {
    username = et_1.getText().toString();
    password = et_2.getText().toString();
    url = "http://rahatmedia.com/ivy_distribution_test/getEmployeeData.php?" +
            "email=" + username +
            "&password=" + password;
    if (et_1.equals("") || et_2.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "some thing went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    String code = jsonObject.getString("code");


                    if (code.equals("login_fail")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error in login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, display.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("name", jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        bundle.putString("email", jsonObject.getString("email"));
                        bundle.putString("license_id ", jsonObject.getString("license_id"));
                        bundle.putString("current_loc ", jsonObject.getString("current_loc"));
                        bundle.putString("status ", jsonObject.getString("status"));
                        bundle.putString("password ", jsonObject.getString("password"));
                        bundle.putString("passcode ", jsonObject.getString("passcode"));
                        bundle.putString("mobile ", jsonObject.getString("mobile"));
                        bundle.putString("idcard ", jsonObject.getString("idcard"));
                        bundle.putString("address ", jsonObject.getString("address"));
                        bundle.putString("emptype ", jsonObject.getString("emptype"));
                        bundle.putString("gst_reg ", jsonObject.getString("gst_reg"));
                        bundle.putString("job_status ", jsonObject.getString("job_status"));
                        bundle.putString("joiningdate ", jsonObject.getString("joiningdate"));
                        bundle.putString("timestamp ", jsonObject.getString("timestamp "));
                        i.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(i);
                        Log.e("response", response);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error in jasonexception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("JSONException response", String.valueOf(e));
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error in ErrorListener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };
        singalton.getinstance(MainActivity.this).addtorequestque(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

This is my singleton class

```
public class singalton {
private static singalton minstance;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private Context context;

private singalton(Context cont) {
    context = cont;
    requestQueue = getRequestQueue();



public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (requestQueue == null) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return requestQueue;
}

public static synchronized singalton getinstance(Context context) {
    if (minstance == null) {
        minstance = new singalton(context);
    }
    return minstance;

}

public <T> void addtorequestque(Request<T> request) {
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

this is my display class

```
public class display extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv_one, tv_two, tv_three, tv_four, tv_five, tv_six, tv_seven, tv_eight, tv_nine, tv_ten, tv_eleven, tv_twelve, tv_thirdeen,
        tv_fourteen, tv_fifteen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);


    tv_one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_1);
    tv_two = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_2);
    tv_three = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_3);
    tv_four = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_4);
    tv_five = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_5);
    tv_six = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_6);
    tv_seven = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_7);
    tv_eight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_8);
    tv_nine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_9);
    tv_ten = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_10);
    tv_eleven = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_11);
    tv_twelve = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_12);
    tv_thirdeen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_13);
    tv_fourteen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_14);
    tv_fifteen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_15);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();


    tv_one.setText("name" + bundle.getString("name"));
    tv_two.setText("email" + bundle.getString("email"));
    tv_three.setText("license_id " + bundle.getString("license_id"));
    tv_four.setText("current_loc " + bundle.getString("current_loc"));
    tv_five.setText("status " + bundle.getString("status"));
    tv_six.setText("password " + bundle.getString("password"));
    tv_seven.setText("passcode " + bundle.getString("passcode"));
    tv_eight.setText("mobile " + bundle.getString("mobile"));
    tv_nine.setText("idcard " + bundle.getString("idcard"));
    tv_ten.setText("address " + bundle.getString("address"));
    tv_eleven.setText("emptype " + bundle.getString("emptype"));
    tv_twelve.setText("gst_reg " + bundle.getString("gst_reg"));
    tv_thirdeen.setText("job_status " + bundle.getString("job_status"));
    tv_fourteen.setText("joiningdate " + bundle.getString("joiningdate"));
    tv_fifteen.setText("timestamp " + bundle.getString("timestamp "));

}
```

Comment: You are trying map JSONObject into JSONArray. I think this part of code is wrong: `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);`

Comment: ok please tell me what should i do???

Comment: Change it to `JSONObject`, read this: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ and maybe nextime use retrofit instead (is much more beginner friendly): http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: Ohh and next time provide sample JSON response too.

Comment: Add  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); instead of JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

Comment: now it is giving this error

Comment: No value for code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your three line from this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
```

to this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
String code = jsonObject.getString("data");
```

Comment: on which line ? Code kaunsa line he

Comment: my logcat is saying this "04-10 19:06:53.034 14293-14293/com.example.ehtisham.login2 E/JSONException response: org.json.JSONException: No value for name
"

Comment: can i get your skype

Answer (score 0):

In your api . 
I have tried your api like this `http://rahatmedia.com/ivy_distribution_test/getEmployeeData.php?email=rasmi@gmail.com&password=123456`

It's giving back a jsonObj. So in your login method You have taken it as `JSONArray` .. Take like `JSONObject js = new JSONObject(responce);`

Comment: For which line its coming now ?

Comment: my logcat is showing this  "04-10 18:36:13.302 13083-13083/com.example.ehtisham.login2 E/JSONException response: org.json.JSONException: No value for code"

Comment: I your api resonce me like this {
type: "1",
data: [ ],
title: "Message",
message: "Data",
_explicitType: null
} There is no "code" in that .. That's why it's showing no value

Comment: so what should i do??

Comment: Send your response .. when you enter in your browser .. Send the response

Comment: tell me please.

Comment: Yes i want what your responce your are getting By that only i can tell

Comment: Or try to print response in your app.. Like Log.v("response",String.valueOf(new JSONObject(responce)));

Comment: http://rahatmedia.com/ivy_distribution_test/getEmployeeData.php?email=nabil@tradenet.com&password=1234

Comment: this is the response i want

Comment: ok change "code" to "data" in your code in this line  String code = jsonObject.getString("data");

Comment: did you get it ?

Comment: final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String code = jsonObject.getString("data");

i think you are telling me to do this

Comment: "No value for name "it saying this now